# How do I trigger inline Javascript that's appended to my page? (ASP.NET webforms)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a page section that is generated by the server, which includes inline javascript that is written by the server (This is ASP.NET webforms). This javascript is used to bind an onchange event to my dropdown, which is in $(document).ready().
When my page section is open on pageload, the $(document).ready() fires and the dropdown is bound correctly. However, when the section is not open on pageload (i.e. I have to click the 'expand' button, which contacts the server to build and load the page section), the inline script doesn't fire.
Basically, the difference is that in one case, the `<script>` tag is in the initial html that is loaded, and in the other case, the `<script>` tag is appended to the initial html after the page is loaded.

This is the inline script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('hi inline!');
    $j(document).ready( function(){ 
        var $emailNameHidden = $j('#hidden_TargetedEmailName');
        $emailNameHidden.on('change', function(){
            van.TargetedEmails.loadTestCaseNameSelect($emailNameHidden.val());
        });
     });
</script>
```

I added the alert to see if I could make it fire by putting it outside the $(document).ready(), but the alert also only fires when the script is included in the initial pageload.

How do I fire the inline script once its been added to the page?

Sidenote: I tried putting this stuff in an external JS file that is included on the page section, but when I tried to bind my dropdown in the external file, the binding fired before the dropdown was finished loading so it didn't get bound, and when I put the binding in a $(document).ready(), the $(document).ready() didn't fire.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the order and specific scenarios going on here, but you could try to wrap it in an `IIFE` like `(function() { alert("HI"); })();`

Answer (score 0):

Just move your client-side logic to `pageLoad` event.

This JavaScript event is fired automatically by ASP.Net framework every time the page loads in the browser i.e.after every post back ( ajax or non-ajax) and on initial load. Document ready event from jquery does not fire when you make an ajax post back in ASP.Net, but `pageLoad` event fires even when an ajax post back is made.

```
function pageLoad() {
//put the document.ready logic here

}
```